# What will really happen in the technical review session before listing our app in AppExchange?

Tags: appexchange, app

We have developed apps that we are preparing to list it in AppExchange listing. It would be a paid app. We already completed a meeting with Account Executive from Salesforce.com. Now, we are going for the second step in the process which is Technical Review.

I am very curious what will really happen in the technical review session. What they will ask? Is that a panel of people at Salesforce.com who will shoot the questions. Would they suggest anything of our code or UI? Really what would happen? How should we prepare for that? Any suggestions on this would be much appreciated.

Please note this is first time we exposed to this process in the way to list our app in AppExchange. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It is a one hour conference call in which you will give a brief demo of your app and/or design to one of salesforce experienced Technical Architects. You will need to be prepared to answer technical questions concerning the architecture of your proposed app.

The below are questions you should be prepared with

1. Describe the application purpose and your target market.
2. Describe at a high level the major processes/workflow within your app.
3. Describe the various roles/personas that will be logging in and how they will be using the application and approximately the number of users per role.
4. What phase of the application lifecycle is the app? What is the release timeline?
5. Will the app include a Force.com Managed Package? If so, what are the major metadata components that the package will contain? (i.e. Apex, Visualforce, Pagelayouts, etc)
6. Roughly how many custom objects, Apex classes (not test classes), Visualforce Pages, Custom Tabs, Reports, Triggers, etc. did you develop?
7. Please name some of your major custom objects.
8. Will the app require any batch processing? If so, how will this be performed (ETL tool, batch APEX, etc.) and what is the schedule (nightly, weekly, monthly, etc.)?
9. Will the app include a cloud based component on a third party hosted environment? If so, briefly describe the technology stack being used and the hosting environment.
10. Will the app include an on premise component?
11. Will the components that reside on the Salesforce platform be integrated with other platforms? What type of integration?
12. If using Salesforce APIs, provide a forecast of the API request volume.
13. What Salesforce standard objects will your app access?
14. Provide a forecast of data volumes for the average customer and the largest customer.
15. Provide a forecast of the number of users for the average customer and largest customer.
16. Will the app use Salesforce Partner Community features? If so, describe the use case.
17. If using Force.com technology, what features are required for your app to function? (i.e. Sales Cloud, Service Cloud, campaigns, etc.)
18. Please describe the number of developers and their skill level using Force.com technologies. Are any developers salesforce certified?
19. Are you planning on a mobile version of the app? If so, will it be HTML5 or Native (iOS, Android, etc.)?
20. Do you require Single Sign-On (SSO) with other apps? If so, do you plan to use OAuth, SAML, etc.? Will you need to integrate to a directory service such as Active Directory or LDAP?
21. Are you planning to pre-populate any data for your customers? If so, how will you do this? Through the APIs? Using CSV files and scripts or through the Data Loader?
22. Are you planning to use a PDO? If so, which PDO?
23. Are you planning to use any Channel Resellers? If so, what is the purpose for using a Channel Reseller (i.e. to penetrate a new market) and what value do they bring? Can you please name your reseller?
24. Please describe your support plan for your app (tiered support via phone or email, customer forums, live agent, etc.)?
25. How will the app be distributed (AppExchange, partner website, Trialforce, etc.)?

Please check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfki4WW45h8) for more details

Check the below [reference materials](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/appvendors/Technical_Review) that will come handy

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mohith. This gives an insight of what it would be.